# Maintain Image Aspect Ratio While Fitting Within Dimensions Without Container Or Whitespace

Tags: css, image, layout

Is it possible to have an image of arbitrary dimensions fit within a given width and height, but without using a fixed container?

Obviously it's easy enough to create a container of specific dimensions and have an img fit within that, however that potentially leads to additional whitespace within the container along the dimension where an image's aspect ratio is shorter or taller than the container.

Is it possible to tell an image:

- it should be as large as possible
- maintain its aspect ratio
- never exceed width of a
- never exceed height of b
- contain no whitespace

To be clear, this needs to involve only CSS and no knowledge of the images' dimensions at runtime.

Comment: width + max-width + max-height + object-fit should do , what have you tried ?

Comment: ..and what is your use-case?

Answer (score -1):

```
img{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

you can check more about object-fit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this using the CSS Property `object-fit: cover;`.

That will tell the image to maintain its aspect ratio, never exceed the containers width and height and not have white space, but in order to keep the aspect ratio and still fit within the container without white space it will cut off the sides of the image.

Comment: *"an image of arbitrary dimensions fit within a given width and height, **but without using a fixed container?**"*

Comment: The container doesn't have to be fixed, as you resize the container the image will be cut more or less from the sides, but it won't lose its aspect ratio and there will be no white space. AND only CSS is involved. As there is no specific use case defined, this resolves the problem: _Maintain Image Aspect Ratio While Fitting Within Dimensions Without Container Or Whitespace_